# How do you match multiple Regex patterns for a single line of text in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have multiple patterns P1, P2, P3,, and so on. These patterns are different Regex patterns to match different variations of DATE.

How do I match these for the same input text most efficiently in a piece of code.

Of course, I can write a for() to loop over these patterns one by one, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This question is somewhat vague. Should the line match one of several patterns, or should it match [multiple patterns simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102484/can-regex-match-intersection-between-two-regular-expressions)?

Answer (score 46):

I think you can use the `|` operator of the regex and put the different regexes in paranthesis to be considered one whole regex to be matched.

`("(P1)|(P2)|(P3)")`

Answer (score 32):

To complement the other answers...

You *can* write one big, hard-to-read pattern using the alternation operator:

```
r1|r2|r3|...|rn
```

where `r1` etc are themselves "fully-fleged" regexes.

However you have to be careful about the *order* of alternations: the first to match wins. That is, if the regex engine is not a POSIX regex engine but java.util.regex's engine isn't.

Therefore, with text `catflap`, using regex:

```
cat|catflap
```

Java will match `cat`; a POSIX regex engine will match `catflap` (the longest, leftmost match).

Sticking with more individual, maintainable patterns is imho a better option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use alternation `(|)` operator to combine multiple patterns for your regexp.

But in case you have various input and you will have to convert them to instance of Date from a string. Then you must follow in a sequence and validate the input one by one. So single regexp may validate the input but it could not be used to any other logic.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.
Having all the patterns in a single pattern and separating the patterns by | worked for me
'((P1)|(P2)|(P3))'

My python code for ref:

```py
input_text = '''Carlisle Farm Specialist F-1 Farm Tire - 12.5L-15 LRF/12 ply (Wheel 
Not Included)       
Evergreen EU72 205/50ZR16 OWL87W RT-5 Truck tire                                        
Goodyear Marathon Trailer Tire w/Galvanized Rim ST215/75R14 LRC (5 Lug On 4.5)          
1 X New Achilles \"ATR Sport\" 265/35ZR18 97W XL High Performance Tires 265/35/18       
Set of 2 ZEEMAX Heavy Duty All Steel ST235/85R16-14PR TL Trailer Tire - 11073           
1 X New Lexani LXHT-106 LT285/70R17/8 118Q BW All Season Performance SUV Tires          
1 X New Nankang N889 Mudstar M/T LT245/75R16 120/116N E/10 Ply ROWL Mud Tires MT        
Pirelli Night Dragon Motorcycle Front Tire 130/90-16 2211500'''
#(Extract : 12.5L-15 LRF/12)
#(Extract : 205/50ZR16 OWL87W)
#(Extract : 265/35ZR18 97W XL)
#(Extract : 130/90-16 )
#(Extract : ST215/75R14 )
#(Extract : ST235/85R16-14PR TL)
#(Extract : LT285/70R17/8 118Q BW)
#(Extract : LT245/75R16 120/116N E/10)

pattern = re.compile(r'(([A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d/\d\d\D\d\d(.[0-9]......([A-Z].([A- 
Z]...)?)?)?)|(\d\d\d/\d\d\D\D?\d\d\s\b(\w\w\w.\w[A-Z])?)|(\d\d\.............))')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `Pattern`s to match dates.

You have `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes to do so.

This said, combining `Patterns` can be done with the **alternation** (`|`) operator on the `String` representation of the `Pattern`.

Comment: `|` is not the `or` operator but the alternation operator