# Can regex match intersection between two regular expressions?

Tags: regex

Given several regular expressions, can we write a regular expressions which is equal to their intersection?

For example, given two regular expressions `c[a-z][a-z]` and `[a-z][aeiou]t`, their intersection contains `cat` and `cut`  and possibly more. How can we write a regular expression for their intersection?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in mathematical regular expressions or in some specific practical implementation such as PCRE?

Comment: @n.m.: in both. For implementation, python or perl.

Answer (score 12):

A logical AND in regex is represented by

```
(?=...)(?=...)
```

So,

```
(?=[a-z][aeiou]t)(?=c[a-z][a-z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: You posted that a few seconds after I added the lookahead part of my answer, we must be mind-melding. :)

Comment: thanks. But what if I want to match the strings in the intersection to a string? The lookaheads don't return matches.  Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154025/how-to-write-a-regex-for-the-intersection-of-two-regexs-which-can-be-used-fo

Comment: The lookaheads return a match if I write parentheses around the patterns: `(?=(c[a-z][a-z]))(?=([a-z][aeiou]t))`

Answer (score 12):

The lookahead examples are easy to use, but technically are no longer regular languages. However it is possible to take the intersection of two regular languages, and that complement is regular.

First note that Regular Expressions can be converted to and from NFAs; they both are ways of expressing regular languages.

Second, by DeMorgan's law,

[image: De Morgan's Law as used in the intersection of two regular languages]

Thus these are the steps to compute the intersection of two RegExs:

- Convert both RegExs to NFAs.
- Compute the complement of both NFAs.
- Compute the union of the two complements.
- Compute the complement of that union.
- Convert the resulting NFA to a RegEx.

Some sources:

- Union and RegEx to NFA: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/lectures/lect_06.pdf
- NFA to RegEx: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/lectures/lect_08.pdf
- Complement of NFA: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13282/complement-of-non-deterministic-finite-automata

Comment: NFA complements could be exponential in size.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's agree on terms. My syntactical assumption will be that

> The intersection of several regexes is one regex that matches strings
>   that each of the component regexes also match.

**The General Option**

To check for the intersection of two patterns, the general method is (pseudo-code):

```
if match(regex1) && match(regex2) { champagne for everyone! }
```

**The Regex Option**

In some cases, you can do the same with lookaheads, but for a complex regex there is little benefit of doing so, apart from making your regex more obscure to your enemies. Why little benefit? Because the engine will have to parse the whole string multiple times anyway.

**Boolean AND**

The general pattern for an AND checking that a string exactly meets regex1 and regex2 would be:

```
^(?=regex1$)(?=regex2$)
```

The `$` in each lookahead ensures that each string matches the pattern and nothing more.

**Matching when AND**

Of course, if you don't want to just check the boolean value of the AND but also do some actual matching, after the lookaheads, you can add a dot-star to consume the string:

```
^(?=regex1$)(?=regex2$).*
```

Or... After checking the first condition, just match the second:

```
^(?=regex1$)regex2$
```

This is a technique used for instance in password validation. For more details on this, see [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

**Bonus section: Union of Regexes**

Instead of working on an intersection, let's say you are interested in the union of the following regexes, i.e., a regex that matches either of those regexes:

1. catch
2. cat1
3. cat2
4. cat3
5. cat5

This is accomplished with the alternation `|` operator:

```
catch|cat1|cat2|cat3|cat5
```

Furthermore, such a regex can often be compressed, as in:

```
cat(?:ch|[1-35])
```

Comment: Can regex (any flavor) accomplish that? Or do we need some programming language?

Comment: I think the pseudo code is to test if a string is in their intersection, not actually represent all strings in their intersection.

Comment: @Tim You are wanting to represent all the strings? Then you are not looking for a regex and I misunderstood your question. To me, `How can we write a regular expression for their intersection?` means that you are looking for a regex that only matches if both patterns are true. Please explain if I am still misunderstanding.

Comment: I would like to write a regex that corresponds to the intersection of the given regexs.

Comment: @Tim With my understanding of `intersection`, that is what the posted answers do, but we may not be understanding each other. If you know how to invite someone to chat (I haven't yet figured it out), we can try to hash that out. :)

Comment: A regex is a set of strings. The intersection of several regexs is the intersection of their sets of strings.

Comment: @Tim Yes that is indeed my understanding. In what way do you feel that the posted answers fail to do that?

Comment: I thought the if statement in your pseduocode is just to test if a string fall into the intersection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55265/discussion-between-zx81-and-tim).

Comment: thanks. But what if I want to match the strings in the intersection to a string? The lookaheads don't return matches.  Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154025/how-to-write-a-regex-for-the-intersection-of-two-regexs-which-can-be-used-fo

Comment: @Tim Sure, I just explained the Boolean AND. To actually match, just add a `.*` after the **AND**. I just edited the answer to reflect this in these subtitles: **Boolean AND**, **Matching when AND**

Comment: FYI simplified the match to `^(?=regex1$)regex2$`, when building a regex for multiple-condition validation I also often forget to replace the final dot-star after the last check by the last check itself. :)

Answer (score 6):

Mathematically speaking, an intersection of two regular languages is regular, so there has to be a regular expression that accepts it.

Building it via corresponding NFAs is probably the easiest. Consider the two NFAs that correspond to the two regexes. The new states Q are pairs (Q1,Q2) from the two NFAs. If there is a transition (P1,x,Q1) in the first NFA and (P2,x,Q2) in the second NFA, then and only then there is a transition ((P1,P2),x,(Q1,Q2)) in the new NFA. A new state (Q1,Q2) is initial/final iff both Q1 and Q2 are initial/final.

If you use NFAs with ε-moves, then also for each transition (P1,ε,Q1) there will be a transition ((P1,P2),ε,(Q1,P2)) for all states P2. Likewise for ε-moves in the second NFA.

Now convert the new NFA to a regular expression with any known algorithm, and that's it.

As for PCRE, they are not, strictly speaking, regular expressions. There is no way to do it in the general case. Sometimes you can use lookaheads, like `^(?=regex1$)(?=regex2$)` but this is only good for matching the entire string and is no good for either searching or embedding in other regexps. Without anchoring, the two lookaheads may end up matching strings of different lengths. This is not intersection.

Comment: thanks. But what if I want to match the strings in the intersection to a string? The lookaheads don't return matches, and the anchors `$` and `^` wont' allow matching in the middle of a string.  Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154025/how-to-write-a-regex-for-the-intersection-of-two-regexs-which-can-be-used-fo

Comment: @Tim you are right, you cannot match in the middle of the string with the lookaheads. That's the limitation of this method.

Answer (score 0):

For And operation, we have something like this in RegEx

(REGEX)(REGEX)

Taking your example

```
'Cat'.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)$/)
["Cat", "C", "a", "t"]
'Ca'.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)$/)
//null
'Cat123'.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)$/)
//null
```

**where**

```
([A-Za-z]+)  //Match All characters
```

**and**

```
([aeiouAEIOU]+) //Match all vowels
```

**Combine them both** will match

([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)

**eg:**

```
'Hmmmmmm'.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)$/)
//null
'Stckvrflw'.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)$/)
null
'StackOverflow'.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)([aeiouAEIOU]+)([A-Za-z]+)$/)
["StackOverflow", "StackOverfl", "o", "w"]
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following you Harpreet, do you think you could maybe post a demo somewhere (maybe [regex101](http://regex101.com))?

Comment: @zx81
I learnt this from this link
http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

Comment: Thank you! But to my eyes, it doesn't seem quite right. Do you realize that the `=?` means "match an `=` sign zero times or once?"...? It is not related to a lookahead. Let me know if I am misunderstanding your intentions.

Comment: For reference, here is an [explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28[A-Za-z]%2B%3D%3F%29) for a subset of your expression, and a page on [lookaheads](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) :)

Comment: @zx81
yes you are right omitting "=" does not effect the solution but output is differ.
what makes me to use this was

'github'.match(/([A-Za-z]+=?)([aeiouAEIOU]+=?)([A-Za-z]+=?)/)

["github", "gith", "u", "b"]

'github'.match(/([A-Za-z]+?)([aeiouAEIOU]+=?)([A-Za-z]+=?)/)

["github", "g", "i", "thub"]

'github'.match(/([A-Za-z]+?)([aeiouAEIOU]+?)([A-Za-z]+=?)/)

["github", "g", "i", "thub"]

'github'.match(/([A-Za-z]+?)([aeiouAEIOU]+?)([A-Za-z]+?)/)

["git", "g", "i", "t"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55269/discussion-between-zx81-and-harpreet-singh).