# How to write a regex for the "intersection" of two regex's, which can be used for matching anywhere in a string

Tags: regex

Given two regex's, can we write a regex which represents their "intersection" in each of the following two difference senses, for matching anywhere in a string?

1. Given two regex's `expr1` and `expr2`, can we write a regex
   which represents the intersection of the two given regex's, in the sense of set intersection, and that
   the  regex can be used to match anywhere in a string?

   For example, `expr1` is `(123|12345|abc|abcde)` and `expr2` is
   `(345|12345|abc|de)`. I would like to find an regex that represents
   `(12345|abc)`.
   So when applying the regex to `blah12345blahabcdeblah`,  the matches
   are `12345` and `abc`, while when applying the regex to
   `blah123blahabcblah`, the match is `abc`.

   `(?=^expr1$)(?=^expr2$).*` has the anchors `^` and `$`, which prevent it from finding matches in the middle of a string.
2. Given two regex's `expr1` and `expr2`, how can we write a regex
   which represents the "intersection" of the two given regex's, in the
   sense that it consists of those strings, each of which

   - appears in at least one of the two regex's, and
   - has a prefix in the rest of the two regex's,

   and the  regex can be used to match anywhere in a string?

   For example, `expr1` is `(123|abcde)` and `expr2` is `(12345|abc)`.
   I would like to find an regex that represents `(12345|abcde)`.
   So when applying the regex to `blah12345blahabcdeblah`, the matches
   are `12345` and `abcde`, while applying the regex to
   `blah123blahabcblah`,  there are no matches (`123` and `abc` are not matches).

The definition of "intersection" in part 2 is more natural than the definition in part 1, when applying the regex to match in the middle of a string:

In the above example, whenever `12345` is a match, `123` also appears, so `12345` seems to be in both `expr1` and `expr2`, and should be in their "intersection".  If `123` were a match, `12345` isn't necessarily a match, for example, in `blah123blahabcblah`, so `123` is not considered in the "intersection". Similar explanation for `abcde` is and `abc` is not in the "intersection".

Thanks!

Comment: Is it not sufficient to find a match with one and then apply the second to the match? If the second matches, you have found your "intersection".

Comment: @Floris: Thanks. What you said seems to work for the first sense, although it is not a single regex for the intersection. What you said seems not work for the second sense.

Comment: in your second definition, does the regex contain only constant strings with `|` between them, or can it be more variable? The former can probably be solved; I doubt if the latter could.

Comment: @Floris: I ask about the latter, i.e. the two given regex's `expr1` and `expr2` are arbitrary. I also wonder how you solve the former case, i.e. the case when both `expr1` and `expr2` are by `|` ?

Comment: Does [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102484/can-regex-match-intersection-between-two-regular-expressions) describe the same problem as this one?

Answer (score 2):

These should do it:

1. `/(?=expr1(.*)$)expr2(?=\1$)/`
2. `/(?=expr1)(?=expr2)/`

Comment: thanks. (1) the first seems to work. I wonder what if intersection of three regex's? (2) the second , however, doesn't capture anything in the "intersection" yet, because it is only two lookaheads.  `(?=expr1)(?=expr2).*` doesn't work either.

Comment: `I wonder what if intersection of three regex's?` Just took care of that one in my answer, but maybe Bergi will have a different idea. :)

Comment: @Bergi: for part 1, there is a counter example. when aplying `(?=(?:1234|12)(.*)$)(?:12)(?=\1$)` to `1234`, there is no match, while the intersection is `12`. The problem is that a captured group inside a lookaround is an atomic group, so no backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1**

I haven't found a solution yet, will look at it some more.

**Answer to Part 2**

Here is a solution that works for regex engines that allow backreferences in lookbehinds, such as .NET and Matthew Barnett's excellent `regex` module for Python.

For your example:

```
(?x)
(?=(12345|abc))(?=(123|abcde)) # AND the expressions
(?: # take the longest match
\1(?<=\2.*) #abcde, \1 is abc
|
\2(?<=\1.*) #12345, \2 is 123
)
```

In general:

```
(?x)
(?=(expr1))(?=(expr2)) # AND the expressions
(?: # take the longest match
\1(?<=\2.*) 
|
\2(?<=\1.*) 
)
```

I think this works... but perhaps there is an edge case I haven't thought about.

Here is some tested Python code.

```
import regex
pattern = r'''(?x)
(?=(12345|abc))(?=(123|abcde)) # AND the expressions
(?: # take the longest match
\1(?<=\2.*) #abcde, \1 is abc
|
\2(?<=\1.*) #12345, \2 is 123
)
'''
myregex = regex.compile(pattern)

print ("--- blah12345blahabcdeblah ---")
for match in myregex.finditer("blah12345blahabcdeblah"):
    print("Overall match: ", match.group(0))

print ("--- blah123blahabcblah ---")
for match in myregex.finditer("blah123blahabcblah"):
    print("Overall match: ", match.group(0))

print ("--- blah12345blahabcdeblah12345 ---")
for match in myregex.finditer("blah12345blahabcdeblah12378"):
    print("Overall match: ", match.group(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the two posts are not the same. Because of `$` and `^`, your second can't be used to match a proper substring of a string. It matches an entire string.

Comment: thanks. (1) in part 1, applying `(?=123)(?:12345)` to `12345`, returns a match `12345` which is not in the intersection. Applying `(?=12345)(?:123)` to `12345` returns a match `123`, which is not in the intersection. (2) in part 2, I test in http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html, that applying `(?=(12345|abc))(?=(123|abcde))(?:\1.*?(?<=\2)|\2.*?(?<=\1))` to `12345blahabcdeblah`, returns no match, while the anticipated matches are `12345` and `abcde`.

Comment: @Tim, what a coincidence, I hadn't seen your comment and was about to post a fix for part 2, as I had found a bug. :) Included some tested Python code. I will look at the problem you report for Part 1.