# Intersection and difference of two regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am doing an exercise on regular expressions and got confused with finding an intersection of two regex.

My first regex matches strings where the first and last characters are the same.
`R1 = ^(.).*\1$`

My second regex excludes strings of the pattern **abba**
`R2 = ^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)`

To find the regex representing the intersection of the two, I tried using lookahead.
`R3 = (?=^(.).*\1$)(?=^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1))`. But this does not work because it matches some strings of pattern **abba**.

So what is the correct way to find the intersection of these two regex? Also, how do I find the difference between two regular expressions? i.e. Find R4 such that R1 is the union of (correct) R3 and R4.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Some string of pattern **abba**"*? Can you include those. As is, I think [`^(.)(.)(?!\2).\1$`](https://regex101.com/r/aDULLs/1) does what you want.

Comment: By abba, I mean to avoid any string that contains the substring of pattern 'abba'. For example, 'trillion', '+--+', etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can regex match intersection between two regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102484/can-regex-match-intersection-between-two-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first pattern directly and rule out `abba` using a negative lookahead:

```regex
^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1)(.).*\1$
```