Merge 2 statements into a single one
I have these two regex statements, they are working as expected.
.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?

For e.g.
नमो first match न
निमो first match नि
.्.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?

For e.g.
व्यैक्ती first match व्यै
I am interested only in the first match and it returns it correctly.
But I am not able to join these 2 statements into a single one.

Update:
I am looking for a way to join these 2 statements so that I can type any word and I will get the correct results. As of now I need to check the word type and apply the appropriate regex to get the correct results.
Statement 1:
.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?

अंबा  > अं
लिंग  > लिं
लैंगिक > लैं
Statement 2:
.्.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?

प्रयत्न  > प्र
व्यंकटेश > व्यं
I am trying to return only the fist match and therefore no need to look around :)

Does this answer your question? Merge multiple REGEX statements

No. It is nowhere near that question.

chatGPT (version 4) suggested .(?:[ािीुूृेैोौं]?|्.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?) that is incorrect.

You would probably help potential answerers, if you could come up with strings that use the latin alphabet. If you cannot (e.g. because then you can find a solution) please state that.

Please provide several different examples of strings that should match and strings that should not match. (Either latin or in that script.)

What is the purpose of the joined regex? Match both examples? (i.e. "or") Match only if both regex trigger on  the same string? (i.e. "and") Please provide examples which clarify that.

If I apply Statement 1 to the words mentioned the second group then I get the incorrect results like प instead of प्र or व instead of व्यं

(.्.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?)|(.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?) ?

chatGPT pointed me in that direction. But I failed to apply. @jhnc you are correct. Please post it as answer

Does this answer your question? Can I "combine" 2 regex with a logic or?

Importance of ORDER of groups is not mentioned in any answer.  @blhsing

@shantanuo A better fitting duplicate is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536282/6890912

The user @jhnc has mentioned the correct command in comment.
(.्.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?)|(.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?)

Using pipe | for OR is a good idea. But the order of groups is very important. For e.g. this returns incorrect results...
(.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?)|(.्.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?)


Whether order matters depends on the regex flavour used. For example, PCRE tries left to right by default, but POSIX ERE mandates longest match.

I tried all flaors mentioned on regex101.com i.e. PCRE, ECMAScript, Python, Golang, Java 8, .NET 7.0 and Rust. Order is important in all cases. But I will keep your comment in mind.

or to avoid repetition, perhaps: (.्)?.[ािीुूृेैोौं]?[ं]?
